# How do I tie my liquid script to the HTML file?

Tags: ruby, email, liquid

Im making a challenge where Im supposed to change an attribute of my html file for another one using liquid, I write the logic of the function, but Im unable to "link it" with my current html. Its something config related or am I missing something? Its the first time I'm using liquid or any ruby related code.

Here's the code snippet:

```
{{% if custom_attribute.${loyalty.has_account} == false %}
{% capture destinationUrl %}https://www.thirdlove.com/account/register {% endcapture %}
{% capture buttonText %}Sing up Now{% endcapture %}
{% else %}
{% capture destinationUrl %} https://www.thirdlove.com/account/login{% endcapture %}
{% capture buttonText %}Sing in Now{% endcapture %}
{% endif %}} <a href="{{destinationUrl}}">{{buttonText}}</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve but as Liquid is a server side rendered language you won't be able to modify HTML depending on user interaction with it.